# why do I have to use int &n instead of int n as parameter?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, parameters

I have to define a function to delete an element in an array, here is the code

```
void delete_element(int a[], int n, int pos)
{
    if (pos>=n)
    pos=n-1;
    else if (pos<0)
    pos=0;
    for (int i=pos-1;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        a[i]=a[i+1];
    }
    --n;
}
```

and here is an example:

```
int n;
printf("Enter the length of the array: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
int A[n]
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
scanf("%d", &A[i]);
delete_element(A,n,2);
```

suppose that n=5 and A = {1,2,3,4,5}, after running the above code, it will print out {1,3,4,5,5}

When I use int n as parameter, the function deletes the element I want but the last element will appear twice in the array. I searched and then found out that by using int &n, the problem will be solved but I don't understand the reasons here. I would really appreciate if you could help me with this!

Comment: This is C++ code, not C.

Comment: Please show a [mre], at a guess the caller of the code doesn't update the size of the array?

Comment: try search for "pass by reference pass by value"?

Comment: This function doesn't delete anything, no matter how `n` is taken. It merely shifts elements in an array.

Comment: @Evg I watched some vids on youtube and all of them said that the idea for deleting an element is to shift the array, idk how to literally delete it

Comment: You can't change the size of a C-style array, so you can't delete elements from it. You can only change their values, and that's what you're doing. To actually delete an element, you have to create a new array of decreased size and copy elements into that new array. However, in C++ you should prefer `std::vector<T>` that gives you a desired semantics of a resizable array.

Comment: To emulate a resizable C-style array, you could keep its "size" in a separate variable, like `n` in your example. When you decrement `n`, you "delete" an element. But technically, this doesn't count as deletion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This function doesn't delete an element in an array actually, because it just overlaps the data at `pos` with the next data, and the size is not changed.
2. It seems that `n` is array's size, so when you use `int n`, the size is passed as value, so outer `n` is not changed. And when you use `int& n`, the size is passed as reference, so `n` will be changed.
3. If you want to delete an element in array actually, you may refer to `pop_back()` or `pop_front()` function of `vector`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I figured it out. But that means if I want to change the value of n inside a function, I have to use int &n instead of int n, did I get it right?

Comment: @ThienAnh Yes. In most cases, reference is faster than value, so you can also use `const int& n` if you don't want to change value.

Comment: References are *not* faster in general and primitive types like `int` should almost *never* be passed by const-ref.

Comment: @Evg yeah, refs are more useful for more complex types, thanks for supplement

Answer (score 1):

If you use `void delete_element(int a[], int n, int pos)`, the arguments are copied to the function.
So if you decrease n by using `--n;`, it will only affect the "local" n, the copy.

If you use `void delete_element(int a[], int& n, int pos)`, the parameter n is padded by referece. This means, there is no local copy used in the function but the variable n from the "outside world".
Therefore, `--n;` will now affect the variable which is given as a parameter to your function.
You could create the same behavior by passing a pointer to the variable. In that case, the address is copied, but instead of the copied address the memory location it points to, the original variable, will be modified.

Comment: thank you so much, I understood it finally.

Comment: Please avoid posting links to gfg. This site is a collection of C++ code examples of extremely bad quality and it better be avoided by beginners.

Comment: oh ok, thanks @Evg. What would be better?

Comment: Typically we refer to introductory books in [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).